# .htaccess not working on directories in conjunction with default WordPress htaccess code

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several WordPress sites where I block users based on their useragents, with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BLEXBot.*$ [NC,OR]
[...]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*gigabot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlekkoBot.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*.* - [F,L]
```

However, without the default WordPress code also in the .htaccess file, the permalinks do not work properly. Default code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The code to block visitors based on the useragent works on all pages on the site when used alone. But, when used in conjunction with the WordPress default code, it only blocks bad useragents on the the root domain (example.com) and no inner pages or directories.

I am looking for a way to use the default WordPress code and the code for blocking users based on useragents in conjunction and have it work on all pages for the site, not just the homepage.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like all you have to do is reverse the order: place your codes _before_ those wordpress codes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick assistance. That seemed to fix it!

Comment: Sure, the rules are processed from top to bottom obviously.